# Tracking user stats in my data model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm getting crazy adding some features to my quiz app based on Rails and Active Record.

This is my actual data model:

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quiz_questions
  has_many :questions, through: :quiz_questions
  belongs_to :user
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
  has_many :answers
  has_many :quiz_questions
  has_many :quizzes, through: :quiz_questions
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quizzes
end
```

Question and answer are obvious: I store the questions and every question has some answer.

The logic now is working right.

User create a quiz, the system take some random questions and add them to the join table.

I must add now some stats: I want to add the possibility for every user to track the right answer percentage and the questions with more errors and I want also to give to every user the possibility to choose a "quiz generation strategy", overriding the "randomness" of the question choice. User for example can create a quiz with questions he never answered (there are about 1200 question in the table and every quiz has 30 questions), or user can create a quiz with questions he wrongs often.

I cannot find a way to add these counters in a smart way. I have my join table, but using the join table I have poor performance. Any idea?

Comment: Any idea where the poor performance comes from? Maybe your queries could be optimized (using indexes maybe). Also, check your logfiles, If you see a lot of select, you probably have an n+1 query

Comment: @MarkMeeus done.. I've optimized the code and now the query are faster. By the way I have an issue that I can't solve. I try for another hour and then I will ask for help! :)

Comment: Are the answer column for the answers users have provided or used to see if the user answered correct?

Comment: @Albin questions and answers are static. 1200 questions and every question has 3 pre-imported answer where just one is correct.
Now I've added a table users_question and when I create an user I pre-populate this table with all the questions. Then to generate a new quiz I take question from the user.questions instead of Questions

Comment: Maybe you could add a user_answer table that joins a user to all answers they have selected and calculate your stats using that table?